# Copying and freeing malloc'ed pointer

Tags: c, pointers, c99

I'm trying to hunt down memory leaks and have found one source. I am malloc'in the pointer in one function and freeing it in another, but I'm missing out on understanding how to copy the value the pointer points to while also being able to free the pointer.

```
Current implementation (with memory leak):

// This code has been greatly simplified
// and as such does not appear to have any purpose
int foo(){
  int bestval = 0;
  char *best;
  char *match;
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
      int returnValue = bar(&best);
      if (returnValue > 10) {
        (1)
         match = best;
      }
  }

  printf("%s", match); 
  (2)    
  return 0;
}


int bar(char ** best) {
  char*s = "Hello!";
  *best = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
  strcpy(*best,s);
  return 0;
}
```

**Two questions**

1. If I had to free memory at (1) rather than (2), how would I do it so that match would still have what was contained in best?
2. Should I be doing strcpy to copy best to match? If so, do I have to do another malloc within foo?

Comment: Assuming there's a free at point two, the code you've posted doesn't leak, however after '2', match isn't valid after this point either... Are you running this code in a loop?

Comment: Why do you require 2 pointers `best` and `match`? You can simply use `best` and `free` it at (2).

Comment: @forsvarir, yes I am running it in a loop, which is why I'm looking at implementing free at (1).

Comment: Is the loop in Foo, or external to it?  If it's in it, it's probably quite relevant to your memory leak... can you ad where the loop starts/ends to your code snippet

Comment: The loop is around bar() - I suspect you might be right - my general sense is that in each of the loops I'm doing a malloc and don;t have the right opportunity to free it. Some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Rio: I've updated my code to include your loop / checks where my comments were

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a stab in the dark, assuming there's a loop in Foo...

```
int foo()
{   
    int bestval = 0;   
    char *best;   
    char *match = 0;    // initialize to null

    // start some loop
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {       

        // fetch the next best value...
        int returnValue = bar(&best);       
        // some check (if best is really best!)
        if (returnValue > 10) {
            // if match has previously been populated, free it
            if(match) {
                free(match);
            }
            // save the new best value
            match = best;   
        }
        else {
           // not saving best in match, so free it!
           free(best);
        }
    }
    // end some loop

    // only do this if match was successful?!?
    if(match) {
        printf("%s", match);    
        // clean up once the best of the best has been used...
        free(match);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I like this, and it makes sense. I will try it and report back to you on my results!

Comment: @Rio: I've just added another free... if you don't save best into match, you need to make sure you free it...

Comment: That last thing was the clincher!

Comment: How do you free an automatic variable on the stack (e.g. `match` and `best`)?!!

Answer (score 1):

In function bar the strcpy should read as

```
strcpy(*best,s);
```

In the main function you can copy the value best points to by

```
strcpy(match, best);
free(best);
```

match needs to point to a valid memory block before. If you do a

```
match = best;
free(best);
```

match will be invalid too because it points at the same freed memory best pointed.

Comment: Sorry, still somewhat in C++ ;-) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the size of the string.
At (1) You would be assigning the address of a memory address that has already been freed, you have to do another malloc to `match*=malloc(sizestr)` and then copy it with memmove or strcpy if you want to free best.

If I understood properly, you want to copy the string into best, then free bests memory and assign ptr to match? if you free best memory before memmoving or strcpying to another location you lose its contents, and if you want to copy it to another location first you need to allocate the memory where you want to copy it to, so you need 2 mallocs on that code.

Answer (score 0):

> If I had to free memory at (1) rather than (2), how would I do it so that match would still have what was contained in best?

If you `free` at position `(1)`, it is not possible to do it so that `match` would still have what was contained in `best`.

> Should I be doing strcpy to copy best to match? If so, do I have to do another malloc within foo?

```
  match = best;
```

With the above statement, both are pointing to the same location. So, there is no need to `strcpy` at all. To do that, allocate memory for `match` to point to whose length is `best+1` and then do a `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the value of a pointer does not copy the underlying memory.  So either, don't `free(best)` until you are done with `match`, or you will need to `malloc` a new buffer, and e.g. `memcpy()` the contents from one buffer to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `malloc` and `strcpy`:

```
match = malloc(strlen(best) + 1);
strcpy(match, best);
```

But, if your implementation provides it you can use the `strdup()` function which is much easier:

```
match = strdup(best);
```

If you don't already have strdup(), it's a good idea to create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your current assignment simply assigns the pointers to the same buffer. If you then `free()` this buffer, you've removed what is contained here (and thus dereferencing it is a bad idea).
You don't need to use `strcpy()` to copy best to match - you'll be better off freeing it after the `printf()` (or the last point that it is needed). There's no point over-complicating things with an extra function call or six, just remember to `free()` memory that you've allocated at the end of each function!